# Lightning Component Helper - Passing Data

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I have been reading and I can't seem to understand one part of the component - controller - helper - apex combo.

If I have a lightning component that is connected to an apex controller...I am confused how an attribute such as `<aura:attribute name="ahg" type="object" />` would know any data. Where is it pulling the data from? What is the value of agh? I can see from a console.log that ahg has a value. I just don't understand how it is set.

Secondly, what is the value of parameters `component, event, helper` in the lightning component's controller's function? Is the param `component` the object? Is there an easy way to console.log() the event? Right now I get back [Object, Object]. When I: `event.toString()` or `console.dir()` I get back useless information.

My end goal is to get the value of a custom object's name and hid/display a div dependent on the value. I need to be able to see the values and know what I am playing with so that I can then pass the appropriate data to the apex controller (if needed).

Component

```
<aura:component controller="CommunityAccountListController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="ahg" type="object" />
```

Controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
```

[image: enter code here]

Comment: It seems you are missing relevant code in your post.

Comment: With the information you have in your post as of now, take a look at this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_client_side_controller.htm) which should clarify your question on the JS controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I see two questions here:

**1) Where are the attribute values coming from**

The value of an `aura:attribute` can really come from four places

- It can be set in javascript 
  `component.set('v.ahg', myVariable)`
- It can be passed as a parameter to the component
  `<c:myComponent ahg="myValue" />`
- It can be defined by default in the attribute
  `<aura:attribute name="ahg" type="String" value="a String">`
- it can come from the flexipage itself (via a Design Attribute)

More details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_attributes.htm). It's hard to apply this to your use case. I don't have enough detail to dig more

**2) What are the values of `component, event, helper`**

The three values contain, in order,

- a reference to the component JS.
  You would use this for various things, like setting/getting attribute values (see my example above) or finding nodes by their "aura:id" (`component.find('myComponentId')`)
- a reference to the event being fired, if any.
  You would use this to catch events and their parameters (`event.getParam('myValue')`)
- a reference to the helper JS
  You would use this to call helper functions (`helper.doSomething()`)

There are a bazillion more uses for the three classes, but these are basics of what you can do with each. You can start [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_bundle.htm) and read the documentation from there.

Comment: this is super helpful thank you. I found where ahg was being set, so this makes sense now. For tapping into the component parameter, is there a way to pull out values by walking up or down the relationships inside of it? Component is a wrapper of an Account record and a custom object record. See attached picture.

Comment: Yes, you can. Get the value into a JS variable and then you use it as anything else.

Comment: @SebastianKessel +1 although: "value ... can come from three places" It can also come from the App Builder via a Design Attribute (for supported data types).

Comment: @sfdcfox I knew I was going to miss one. Will update for future readers.